# Ruby on Rails: How to have ActiveRecord callback load a shared variable between callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a couple of `before_save` and `after_save` callbacks that need to share an instance of an object between each other in a Ruby on Rails project. I thought that adding an additional method called `load_object` where I load the object into an instance variable would do the trick. This worked fine for the `before_save` validations, but the object didn't persist to the `after_save` chain of methods. Is there anyway to make sure it's around for both sets while keeping my code DRY?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that's strange, the callbacks run on the same instance, and any instance variable should still be available (though not persisted). but you can always use an `around_save` callback

```
around_save :do_something

def do_something
  #beforesave things
  yield
  #aftersave things
end
```